# Supply Credentials when Git Clone

Tags: git, libgit2sharp, bonobo

i am using Bonobo.Git.Server as my Git Repo Server.

how can i pass in credientials to clone a repo? Below is the c# code i use. but i keep getting this error,

**ERROR_An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Invalid (Error). Failed to parse supported auth schemes: The operation identifier is not valid.**

```
Credentials cred = new Credentials();

cred.Username = "pspl\admin";
cred.Password = "admin";

Repository.Clone("http://localhost:50287/Repo1.git", @"C:\Users\gohks\Desktop\testFolder", false, true, null, null, cred);
```

BTW can possible to send current logon windows crediential?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're relying on **[Windows authentication](http://bonobogitserver.com/windows-authentication/)** to communicate with Bonobo.

LibGit2Sharp doesn't support this by default. However you may find some help on the work done by **[@GasparNagy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26530/gaspar-nagy)** on this **[post](http://gasparnagy.com/2013/11/connect-to-tfs-2013-git-repository-with-libgit2sharp/)** to support NTLM authentication.

Supporting source code can be found **[here](https://github.com/gasparnagy/Sample_NtlmGitTest/blob/master/NtlmGitTest/HttpClientSmartSubtransport.cs)**.

Comment: I not using windows authentication, thou username looks like one.

Comment: i manage to get it worked. i cannot supply domain in the username field.

Comment: *"i cannot supply domain in the username field"* -> I'm not sure to understand this statement. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: *"i manage to get it worked."* -> Awesome! Maybe could you add an answer to this question describing what changes you've done in order to successfully communicate with Bonobo Git Server? That may help later other users with a similar issue.

Comment: in my code, Username = 'pspl\admin' but there is an error. after i change the Username = 'admin' the authentication pass thru. and clone was successful.

Comment: I read @GasparNagy post, and i download his project. but i keep missing Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices reference. Tired to install TFS express. But still cannot find reference. where can i get this library?

Comment: @KSKianSeng I think this may be a good fit for a new StackOverflow question.

Comment: I strongly recommend using the NtlmGitSession / HttpClientSmartSubtransport implementation from my sample. That does not depend on the VS assembly (just on the patched native git dll).